# Background image should be above the background colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to add the  div with background png image and that background image should be top to the two columns divs with coral and steelblue background colors with in the row div.so kindly tell me the css changing.
        here is image
        [the glass image should b above the two divs but rmain behind the circles and text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MQl3.jpg)

```
    <section>
    <div class="bg-hands row"> <!--row div start-->
        <div class="left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
                <img src="/images/img_avatar2.png" class="img-circle img-responsive" style="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <h2>lorem ipsem</h2>
                <h4>doller sit amet</h4>
                <hr>
                <p id="p-left">Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis.</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="right col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left">
                <img src="/images/img_avatar2.png" class="img-circle img-responsive" style="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <h2>lorem ipsem</h2>
                <h4>doller sit amet</h4>
                <hr>
                <p id="p-right">Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis.</p>   
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!--below css-->
.left {
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
.right {
    color: white;
    background: steelblue 
}
.pull-right {
    padding: 20px;
}
.pull-left {
    padding: 20px;
}
.img-circle {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.bg-hands {
    background: url("/images/opacityimg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.text-center {
    padding: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some info also please? What you are trying to achieve exactly and then I will post an answer

Comment: This is a poorly written question with no explanation, please see here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask - how to ask a clear, concise question.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this solution:
This fiddle is without Bootstrap.

```css
  .left
    {
        background-color: coral;
        color: white;
    }
   .right
   {
       color: white;
       background: steelblue 
   }
  .pull-right
   {
       padding: 20px;
   }
  .pull-left 
   {
     padding: 20px;
   }
  .img-circle-coral
  {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
     
  }
    .img-circle-blue
  {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
     background-color: steelblue;
  }
 .bg-hands
 {
    //background: url("http://xiostorage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/test.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
 }
.text-center
 {
    padding: 80px;
 }
 
 .coral {
   background-color: coral;
 }
 
 .steelblue {
   background-color: steelblue;
 }
```

```html
<section>
          <div class="bg-hands row"><!--row div start-->
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
              <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
                 <img src="http://xiostorage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/test.png" class="img-circle coral img-responsive" style="">
              </div>
             <div class="left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="width: 100%">
                 <h2>lorem ipsem</h2>
                 <h4>doller sit amet</h4>
                 <hr>
                 <p id="p-left">Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis.</p>
          </div>  
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left">
              <img src="http://xiostorage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/test.png" class="img-circle steelblue img-responsive" style="">

          </div>
             <div class="right col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="width: 100%">
                 <h2>lorem ipsem</h2>
                 <h4>doller sit amet</h4>
                 <hr>
                 <p id="p-right">Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis.</p>      
          </div> 
          </div>
          </div>
      </section>
```

OK?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a better explanation. You have only posted a script.

If the image has an opacity and you want to have a different colour behind it, then you can just add something like this in the CSS :

```
background: #fff url("/images/opacityimg.png");
```